# when change from Angular 4 to Angular 7

Tags: angular

I tried to convert Angular4 to Angular 7. I faced an error below like this

```
error TS2305: Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import line must be wrong (because of the double quote). Your import line should look like:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
```

And `OpaqueToken` has been deprecated in favor of `InjectionToken` so you should consider updating your code (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14763).

Comment: Exactly, I imported like this import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
But, Its thrown an error

Comment: You need use the new `InjectionToken` instead.

Comment: Thank you, buddy, If I changed InjectionToken instead of OpaqueToken. I faced another error like 
"No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency"

Comment: Ok, if you can't find your way around, open another question with your precise issue (and close this one by accepting the answer :) )